# Members of struct lose value when created by factory method

Tags: rust, struct, scope, vulkan, ash

I hope that I'm able to explain my problem as clear as possible. I'm working on a Rust application that uses Vulkan.

I ran into some trouble creating the graphics pipeline. I found the issue, but I have no idea what and why it is happening.

First let me show what works. For creating the graphics pipelines I need to create something called a `PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo`. This struct (and some others) I then use to create a `GraphicsPipelineCreateInfo`.

The `width` and `height` properties of swapchain_extent are set to 1600 and 1200 respectively.

```rust
    let viewports = [Viewport::builder()
        .x(0.0)
        .y(0.0)
        .width(swapchain_extent.width as f32)
        .height(swapchain_extent.height as f32)
        .min_depth(0.0)
        .max_depth(0.0)
        .build()];

    let scissors = [Rect2D::builder()
        .offset(Offset2D::builder().x(0).y(0).build())
        .extent(swapchain_extent)
        .build()];

    let viewport_state_create_info = PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo::builder()
        .scissors(&scissors)
        .viewports(&viewports)
        .build();

    let graphics_pipeline_create_infos = [GraphicsPipelineCreateInfo::builder()
        .viewport_state(&viewport_state_create_info)
        .build()];
```

This all works perfectly.

To make my code more structured I created a helper function that takes care of creating the `PipelineViewPortStateCreateInfo`:

```rust
fn create_viewport_state_create_info(extent: Extent2D) -> PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo {
    let viewports = [Viewport::builder()
        .x(0.0)
        .y(0.0)
        .width(extent.width as f32)
        .height(extent.height as f32)
        .min_depth(0.0)
        .max_depth(0.0)
        .build()];

    let scissors = [Rect2D::builder()
        .offset(Offset2D::builder().x(0).y(0).build())
        .extent(extent)
        .build()];

    PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo::builder()
        .viewports(&viewports)
        .scissors(&scissors)
        .build()
}
```

And I call it from my other function like this:

```rust
    let viewport_state_create_info = create_viewport_state_create_info(swapchain_extent);

    let graphics_pipeline_create_infos = [GraphicsPipelineCreateInfo::builder()
        .viewport_state(&viewport_state_create_info)
        .build()];
```

I don't see a problem with this code. However when I run this code the Vulkan validation layer throws this error back at me:

```
VALIDATION [VUID-VkViewport-width-01770 (-1542042715)]: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkViewport-width-01770 ] | MessageID = 0xa4164ba5 | vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(): pCreateInfos[0].pViewportState->pViewports[0].width (0.000000) is not greater than 0.0. The Vulkan spec states: width must be greater than 0.0
```

Even though `swapchain_extent.width` is set to 1600.

In the debugger I see that it is indeed 1600, but when I step into the build function of the `GraphicsPipelineCreateInfoBuilder` suddenly both width and height become 0.0

Is this some scoping issue? If it is, isn't the compiler supposed to protect me against it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in your assumption. It is a scoping issue.

The issue is that while [`PipelineViewportStateCreateInfoBuilder`](https://docs.rs/ash/latest/ash/vk/struct.PipelineViewportStateCreateInfoBuilder.html) is bound by `'a` and **references** `viewports` and `scissors`. The issue is that [`PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo`](https://docs.rs/ash/latest/ash/vk/struct.PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.html) does not, and instead keeps pointers (not references) to `viewports` and `scissors`.

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo {
    ...
    pub p_viewports: *const Viewport,
    pub p_scissors: *const Rect2D,
    ...
}
```

So the second that `create_viewport_state_create_info()` returns, then both `viewports` and `scissors` are **dropped**. So the pointers in [`PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo`](https://docs.rs/ash/latest/ash/vk/struct.PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.html) are now invalid.

The reason that the compiler isn't able to catch this. Is because when [`build()`](https://docs.rs/ash/latest/ash/vk/struct.PipelineViewportStateCreateInfoBuilder.html#method.build) is called, it returns a [`PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo`](https://docs.rs/ash/latest/ash/vk/struct.PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.html) which is not bound by any lifetime anymore. It could in theory. However, [`ash`](https://crates.io/crates/ash) is simply mirroring the definition of [`VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo`](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.html).

The [`PipelineViewportStateCreateInfoBuilder`](https://docs.rs/ash/latest/ash/vk/struct.PipelineViewportStateCreateInfoBuilder.html) is actually doing exactly what you would do in that case. It contains a [`PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo`](https://docs.rs/ash/latest/ash/vk/struct.PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.html) and uses a [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) for the unused lifetime.

```rust
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct PipelineViewportStateCreateInfoBuilder<'a> {
    inner: PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo,
    marker: ::std::marker::PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}
```

Comment: Thank you taking the time for this thorough explanation 